# How to sort values in a column depending on values on different columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

I have a large table in which I want to sort as follows:

- Sort by column F
- If a value in column F is between 5000 and 6000, sort these rows by values in column B
- If a value in column F is between 6000 and 8000, sort these rows by values in column C

My workaround is having a separate column assigning values to each row by an IF formula and sorting this row only.

Can it be done quicker and more elegant?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Please take the quick [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn how StackExchange Q&A sites differ from internet forums. Please also see Asking- and Answering -sections in the [Help](https://superuser.com/help). This question could be [improved](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) by adding more details. 1) The current formula (enclosed in the curly brackets `{}` to preserve formatting)  2) Screenshot of the actual results of the formula 3) Screenshot of the expected results. [From Review](https://superuser.com/review/first-questions/1084468)

Comment: Do you want 2 conditions are met at the same time and then sorted?

Comment: My first instinct would be to do a multi-column sort, but I have a feeling that's not what you want. What happens to values below 5000 and above 8000? It would be helpful to see sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Can you clarify if you need to filter/sort in place (which would be your solution or VBA) or if you want the output to show up somewhere else (formula nesting `SORT(SORT(FILTER()))` may accomplish, but it depends)

Answer (score 0):

I am the LAST person who will point someone directly to using VBA rather than a cell-side formula that turns out to exist.

Not to denigrate VBA! It's clearly the gold standard for anything not simple and easy to do, but especially for things that head off the reservation.

But in this case, I do not see author or user interaction solving the problem via formulas and functionalities Excel offers AND somehow being "elegant" and so replacing what you do now in any meaningful way.

Even offering a workable `SORT()` function formula simply replaces the current approach and uses the same helper column. It might be a more elegant-seeming at first, but wouldn't be essentially different than what works now.

VBA on the other hand, could do it very simply. A first approach could be to have VBA sort the whole Table or range completely using column F. Then have VBA look for the block of rows that meet the first condition (and so sort by column B) and sort again, but just those rows. Rinse and repeat for the other condition (sorting them by column C).

A second-level approach would be to set a keystroke combo to initiate the macro, or place a button a user can click to initiate it. "Baby steps" as the movie (book, actually, I'm sure but I only saw the movie) had it.

Need to sort a third batch? Easy peasy.

Note that this is not the same AT ALL as doing a three column sort key sort. That's why VBA is so well suited to it.

I am not the one to write the code for you though. But the above would be a simple, yet complete, guideline for anyone you asked or engaged to do so.